# Что такое энтерпрайз(Enterprise) в контексте программирования?

Tags: терминология

Иногда встречаю понятие *энтерпрайз программирование* или *энтерпрайз код*. 
Какое этому понятию можно дать определение ? И почему часто это употребляется как что-то негативное?

P.S. Понимаю что вопрос не зависит от языка, но ответ интересует относительно .Net платформы.

Comment: [_Enterprise software, also known as enterprise application software (EAS), is computer software used to satisfy the needs of an organization rather than individual users._](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_software)

Comment: Это решения для большого бизнеса, для тех у кого много денег. Когда денег не хватает, то становится обидно, что  попользоваться не удастся. Эта обида иногда  перерастает в негативное отношение (зачастую  вполне справедливо, поскольку обещанные  фичи часто все же  не стоят таких денег) к таким решениям.

Comment: @avp, ну негатив это с точки зрения пользователя продукта. А с точки зрения программистов в чем проблема?

Comment: Далеко не всем программистам суждено участвовать в таких разработках (не в качестве "негров").

Comment: Добавлю свой вопрос с теме. Попытался найти объяснение, что значит "Ъ-программисты", но не смог ничего подходящего найти, дайте пожалуйста определение.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Всякие сервисы, базы данных и их интеграции между собой. Чаще всего это инфраструктура организаций, всякие CRMы, 1Сы и прочее. Нелюбимо творческими программистами за то, что это b2b, которым нельзя похвастаться перед друзьями, а Ъ-программисты ругают "галерных" программистов, что работа эта не творческая, рутинная, а исполнители - бестолковые и неквалифицированные, которые не могут в бородатые стартапы. Ну и так как этими системами клиентов не завлекают, то там гнездятся тонны легаси-кода.

Можно сказать, что зависит от языка. В подавляющем большинстве случаев это Java и .NET.

Comment: Немного ситация прояснилась. Но кто такие Ъ-программисты? гугл тоже не знает, кажется :) А "галерные программисты" ? P.S. я не местный но русскоговящий, поэтому мне много не ясно :)

Comment: @koks_rs Первое - ну...очень крутые =) Значение похоже на "тру-...". Про приставку "Ъ" можно на лурке почитать (гугл подскажет дорогу). Второе - отсылка к рабам на галерах в Древнем Риме (крупные, бюрократизированные компании называют "галерами").

Answer (score 2):

Если в лоб:

Постройка дома/дачи-это обычные проекты, хоть и бывают сложные

Строительство МКД на 1000+ квартир по ГОСТу в 70-100+ лет эксплуатации это Энтерпрайз.

По моим наблюдениям, Энтерпрайз решение должно обладать следующими характеристиками:

1) широкий масштаб разработки (международная компания или хотя бы специалисты из разных городов и областей, разные направления специалистов, часто решение находится на стыке научных изысканий)

2) большое количество пользователей (от 1 млн пользователей примерно)

3) решение, которое охватывает целую отрасль и более (т е находится в топе среди подобных решений в рамках мира или хотя бы большой страны/группы стран)

4) решение стабильное, отказоустойчивое, предсказуемое и требующее минимум изменений с течением долгого времени эксплуатации (т е даже спустя десятилетия, данное решение будет оптимальным решением вне зависимости от смены технологий, подходов и прочих как внешних, так и внутренних условий)

Почему негативное? Это субъективно-код получается неубиваемый, живучий и местами сложно понимаемый. Здесь нужно терпение и быстро результат нельзя получить, равно как и все новомодное встраивается очень медленно в виду сложности решения.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise-разработка – это промышленная разработка программного обеспечения, которая характеризуется:

- большими и сложными проектами
- длительным сроком разработки (множественные релизы, несущие новый функционал)
- разработку ведет команда (часто большая)

Главные приоритеты промышленной разработки:

- надежность
- предсказуемость
- интеграция с другими enterprise системами в рамках предприятия или отрасли
- безопасность, защищенность
- гибкость

В промышленной разработке широко применяются всевозможные стандарты и формализованные процессы. Например, Agile.

Противоположностью промышленной является "кустарная" разработка, которая характеризуется:

- небольшими разовыми заказами (без сопровождения и развития)
- небольшой командой (часто – один разработчик)

Приоритетами "кустарной" разработки являются:

- скорость разработки
- качественный дизайн и юзабилити
- быстрое удовлетворение сиюминутных желаний клиента

В отличие от "кустарной" промышленную разработку часто (и возможно заслуженно) критикуют за:

- устаревшие технологии (legacy code)
- узкую специализацию разработчиков
- бюрократию и долгие сроки (в первую очередь из-за большого количества согласований)
- низкую эффективность (из-за необходимости следовать стандартам и процессам)
- подавление творчества